# Deleting a zero-byte file from the sdcard

Tags: android, file, android-sdcard, delete-file

I have a few zero-byte files in my app folder inside the sdcard which I am not able to delete.

```
final String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+"AppFolder"+"/"+"Music";
         File file=new File(path,filee);
         if(file.exists())
         {
          boolean delete=file.delete();
          Log.d("TAG",""+delete);
         }
```

'filee' here is the name of the file(.mp3).This code does not work as technically the file does not exist.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: Is this a typo here? File file=new File(path+filee); Also path does not end in a '/' so adding a filename without '/' preceeding it will not be looking for the correct file.

Comment: no...I have another filee is a string and file is the actual file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should be ok:

```
 File file = new File(path);
 boolean isDeleted = file.delete();
```

First, please check with the permission and make sure you have this permission:

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

And your path should be something like this:

```
/sdcard/YourDirectory/filee.mp3
```

Comment: Thank you that worked,I had included android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Answer (score 0):

here is your error `"AppFolder"+"/"+"Music" ;`
try :
`"AppFolder"+"/"+"Music" + "/";`

Also make sure you are giving the extension in `filee` variable too.

eg : `filee="song.mp3"`